# SQL Query using IN() and a mandatory value

Tags: sql, inner-join

I have an INNER JOIN query which grabs a country name depending on the values in the joined table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT countryName, countrySlug
FROM countries AS Country
INNER JOIN countries_networks AS n ON Country.id = n.country_id
AND n.network_id IN ( 6, 7, 8, 9, 14 )
```

However, I now need to `select` the ones that meet the **IN() criteria**, and also must contain the **network 2**.

I obviously can't just add 2 to the IN(), as I need 2 to be mandatory, with at least one of the others.

Can someone help, I have a feeling its ridiculously simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (double join?):

```
SELECT DISTINCT countryName, countrySlug, n.country_id, n2.country_id
FROM countries AS Country
INNER JOIN countries_networks AS n ON Country.id = n.country_id
AND n.network_id
IN ( 6, 7, 8, 9, 14 )
INNER JOIN countries_networks AS n2 ON Country.id = n2.country_id
AND n2.network_id = 2
```

NOTE: The `n.country_id, n2.country_id` values are shown only for be able to check the result

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  countryName, 
  countrySlug
FROM countries AS Country
INNER JOIN countries_networks AS n  ON Country.id   = n.country_id
                                   AND n.network_id IN (6, 7, 8, 9, 14) 
WHERE Country.id IN (SELECT id
                     FROM countries_networks 
                     WHERE network_id = 2
                       AND id IS NOT NULL);
```

This will insure that any selected country must have `network_id = 2`.

Answer (score 1):

First, drop the `DISTINCT` by replacing the join with an `EXISTS` subquery. Then you can add another subquery to take care of the extra requirement:

```
SELECT countryName, countrySlug
FROM countries AS c
WHERE EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM countries_networks AS n 
        WHERE c.id = n.country_id
          AND n.network_id IN ( 6, 7, 8, 9, 14 )
      )
  AND EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM countries_networks AS n 
        WHERE c.id = n.country_id
          AND n.network_id = 2
      ) ;
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT countryName, countrySlug
FROM countries AS Country
INNER JOIN countries_networks AS n ON Country.id = n.country_id
AND n.network_id=2 And n.network_id IN (2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 14 )
```